# Express - Serve folders based on request

Tags: node.js, express

**For ExpressJs and NodeJs**
Assume I have 3 types of users in my application.
Based on type of user(extracting from cookie), how to serve particular folder based on condition?

Say I have 3 folders x, y and z.
I have condition which says for user_type x -> serve folder x contents.
Same with y and z.

I tried following code but it didn't worked.

```
function checkCookieMiddleware(req, res, next) {
     const req_cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '');

    if(req_cookies.type){
        if(req_cookies.type === "X"){
            express.static(basePath + "/client/x");
        }
        else if(req_cookies.type === "Y"){
            express.static(basePath + "/client/y");
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
  }  


    app.use(checkCookieMiddleware, express.static(basePath + "/client/z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this NPM package - [express-dynamic-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-dynamic-static) - that looks to do what you are looking for. If you don't want to pull in another dependency, the [source code](https://github.com/baldlion/express-dynamic-static/blob/master/index.js) for it is fairly small, you could copy it as a custom middleware yourself.

If you were to use it, then I think you code might look something like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const dynamicStatic = require('express-dynamic-static')();

const app = express();
app.use(dynamicStatic);

function checkCookieMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    const req_cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '');

    if (req_cookies.type) {
        if (req_cookies.type === 'X') {
            dynamicStatic.setPath(basePath + '/client/x');
        } else if (req_cookies.type === 'Y') {
            dynamicStatic.setPath(basePath + '/client/y');
        } else {
            // Z
            dynamicStatic.setPath(basePath + '/client/z');
        }
    }

    next();
}

app.use(checkCookieMiddleware);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try this package and revert you if still have some doubts.